# How to add a collection when register a new user using Symfony 2.6 FosUser 1.3

Tags: symfony, controller, overriding, fosuserbundle

I'm using FosUserBundle 1.3 and Symfo 2.6.

I need to add addresses (collection type) when I register a new User. Is it possible ?

Address entity has the owner side so when I want to register (create) the user, it returns me an error (contraint integrity userID cannot be null).

I see that I can do something like that into the Controller before the flush :

```
if($entity->getAddresses() !== null){
  foreach($entity->getAddresses() as $address){
    $address->setUser($entity);
  }
}
```

Is it best practice ?

Now, where can I do that with Fos ? I think that here seems to be the right place but I'm not sure and can I override it ?

**RegistrationFormHandler**

...

```
public function process($confirmation = false)
{
    $user = $this->createUser();
    $this->form->setData($user);

    if ('POST' === $this->request->getMethod()) {
        $this->form->bind($this->request);

        if ($this->form->isValid()) {

            // I WOULD LIKE TO COPY MY CODE HERE
            // 

            $this->onSuccess($user, $confirmation);

            return true;
        }
    }

        return false;
    }
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will work since 2.0 version.**

I think you should register you own `EventListener` that will listen to `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` or `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` and then you can add there your custom logic without controller overriding. Something like:

`RegistrationListener` class:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'completed'
        );
    }

    public function completed(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();

        // add your custom logic here
    }
}
```

and services.yml:

```
app_listener.registration:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Remember to add proper dependencies to your listener class if needed.

**For 1.3 version**

You need to create a child bundle whose parent is FOSUserBundle and ovveride: `RegistraionController::registerAction` in your case:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
        $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

        $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            // you custom logic

            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
            } else {
                $this->authenticateUser($user);
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
            }

            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can I do that with FOS 1.3 ? I red that events are with the last version. wrong ?

Comment: You are right - this will work only since 2.0 version. With 1.3 you need to override `controller->registerAction`

Comment: Why don't you just update you FOSUserBundle to latest version if you are using sf 2.6?

Comment: Can I override RegistrationFormHandler.php (class in Form>Handler) called in the controller registerAction ?

Comment: Is this new version of FOS stable ? How can I check that ?

Comment: Yes, you can override RegistrationFormHandler - all you need is here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md#overriding-form-handlers

Comment: It's not stable yet but i'm using it in my production products.